# import an excel file and request a few ports in the background with the error "The temporary upload location [/tmp/** is not valid"

Tags: java

I I want to ask a question about there.
When I use springboot service, I import an excel file and request a few ports in the background with the error "The temporary upload location [/tmp/tomcat.8266510552085071302.****/work/Tomcat/ localhost/ROOT] is not valid", the query is because the linux temporary file does not exist (seems to be because linux will periodically clean up the temporary folder), how do I need to solve this problem? Restarting the service will solve it temporarily, but it will still appear later。I took the way to add "spring.http.multipart.location=/opt/data/upload" in application.properties, after restarting the service, this folder is not automatically created, I need to manually Do I need to create this folder manually? If this works, do I need to write a timed task to clean up the contents of "/opt/data/upload" periodically? Or is there a better way to do it? Looking forward to your reply!

The error message is as follows
{
"timestamp": 1686015218374,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException",
"message": "Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: The temporary upload location [/tmp/tomcat.8266510552085071302.1114/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT] is not valid",
"path": "/importDevices"
}

I tried the above method, restarted the service and found that there was no "/opt/data/upload" directory, so I created this directory manually, but when I requested the interface again, I found that the modification date of this temporary directory had not changed, and the /tmp directory that comes with the linux system had changed (it seems that the temporary files still exist in this directory that comes with the system, and guess After a period of time, it will still be automatically cleaned up by the system, and the previous problem will still occur if it is not used frequently), this method does not seem to work or need to change the place